# Git not pushing all files

Tags: git, github

I have a `www` folder in which I have all my project files within their respective folder. I update those individual projects in git regularly.

Recently I tried pushing the whole `www` folder in a complete different repository but it ignored the Projects which were already pushed into their respective repo.

[image]

Here I have `pset7` folder as a complete different repo, But when I try to push the parent (ie `www`) its ignoring all the files in `pset7` and showing as empty directory on GitHub.

Comment: From the command line in your `www` folder type `git log pset7` and tell us what the output is.

Comment: have a look at git submodule docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Comment: Thankyou very much @pedrorijo ... that exactly what I wanted!

Comment: while it's not a direct answer, it should help you better understand the problem (I don't have enough experience with submodules to give you an 100% crorrect answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you push the parent repo, it will not push the submodules contained within it.  You can use the command `git push --recurse-submodules`.

Additionally, you can use the options `check` and `on-demand`:

- > If `check` is used, it will be checked that all submodule commits that changed in the revisions to be pushed are available on a remote.
  >   Otherwise the push will be aborted and exit with non-zero status.
  >   If on-demand is used, all submodules that changed in the revisions to be pushed will be pushed.
- > If `on-demand` was not able to push all necessary revisions it will
  >   also be aborted and exit with non-zero status.

...So use the command `git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand` within your parent directory and you will also push all the submodules (i.e. repos) one level down from the parent repo.